# Sheets API BatchUpdate a Specific Worksheet, Native Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

How do I specify the specific worksheet within this Google Sheet (sheetId) that I want to insert rows into? With the below code, it inserts rows into the first worksheet. I know how to specify the worksheet with the append API call (`spreadsheets/' + sheetId + '/values/' + range + ':append`) but that same syntax does not work here for the batchUpdate call (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#insert_an_empty_row_or_column).

What am I missing?

```
const resource = {
  requests: [
    {
      insertDimension: {
        range: {
          dimension: 'ROWS',
          startIndex: 1,
          endIndex: 5
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};

var url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + sheetId + ':batchUpdate';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST",url,false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(resource));
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered I need to include a "sheetId" field inside the "range" object in my request. This sheetId is NOT the same as the spreadsheetId (which I originally thought). It's also not the name of the individual worksheet, but in fact a number assigned by Google, that correlates to the individual worksheet.

I can only know this number by calling spreadsheets.get, which is the following URL: `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + spreadsheetId + '?fields=sheets.properties`.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet#determine_sheet_id_and_other_properties

I included the "fields" parameter in the above URL in order to get only the properties of the sheet (which includes sheetIds, names, etc) and not all the cell data. I can use the return object to see all worksheets within the spreadsheet and their sheetIds, titles, and other information. I can use that sheetId to make the call I originally wanted to make with batchUpdate.